# What is the default META key for Irssi (IRC) on macOS?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, irc

What is the default Meta key for Irssi (IRC) in Terminal?

I noticed that I can use the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key as Meta key if enabled in Terminal settings, but this prevents me from using it to type special characters.

If there is no default Meta key, is it possible to define one different from <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>?

Comment: The Meta key doesn't change per application.  Are you asking *how to remap the Meta key?*

Comment: Yes, remapping it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Irssi documentation](https://irssi.org/documentation/startup/#basic-user-interface-usage), it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which I believe the author meant <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> to be on macOS, as this is how <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> is usually used on macOS compared to Windows.

However, on macOS Mojave, it is actually <kbd>Esc</kbd>.